# Associating model A with model B AND model B's association

Tags: database-design, associations, relational-database, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many

Let's imagine a bus system.

Here's the easy part:

- Route has many Directions
- Stop has many Routes

But what if we need to know which specific route directions go to each stop? Is it bad practice to associate the stops with directions?

- Stop has many Directions

Notice that now the Stop model is associated directly with the Route model, *and also* with the Direction model. This feels weird to me, because the Route model is associated with the Stop model in two different ways: directly, and indirectly through Direction.

Here's an attempt at a diagram:

```
 Route
 |    \
Stop — Direction
```

**Does this smell bad to you?**

I *could* remove the association between Route and Stop, because technically I can find this through `Route->Direction(s)->Route` but there are a number of situations where we will also want to simply know which routes pass through a stop. Does the wise programmer pick only one of the relationships? Or is it acceptable to have both?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if direction refers to the direction the bus is traveling as it approaches the stop or as it leaves the stop. A stop on or near a corner could be approached from one direction and left in another. It doesn't matter in the design, but it will matter when constructing a route from the data.

Assume you have a table of Stops and a table of Routes. What you describe is an m-m relationship between the two: a Route consists of zero or more Stops and a Stop may appear in zero or more Routes.

Now, however, you want to add direction to the mix. That's fine but you must keep in mind that "direction" is an attribute of the relationship. Neither Stop nor Route can be described by "direction." So the cross table would look like this:

```
create table RouteStops(
  RouteID  int  not null references Routes( ID ),
  StopIncr smallint not null -- Stop #1, stop #2, etc.
  StopID   int  not null references Stops( ID ),
  Direction char( 2 ) not null, -- 'N', 'W', 'NW', etc
  constraint PK_RouteStops primary key( RouteID, StopIncr )
);
```

So if Route #15 consisted of 31 stops, there would be 31 entries in this table.

```
RouteID StopIncr StopID Direction
     15        1    417 N
     15        2    122 N
     15        3    213 E
     ...
     15        17   122 S
     ...
```

You need a field like StopIncr so you can designate the order of the stops within the route: first stop of the route, second stop of the route, etc.

Notice stop #122 is visited as the third stop and as the 17th stop when the bus is going in the opposite direction.

**Update:**
It sounds like "direction" is an attribute of stop that indicates that it is or may be used by a route going in that direction. That can be modeled by a simple table.

```
create table StopDirection(
  StopID    int  not null references Stops( ID ),
  Direction char( 2 ) not null, -- 'N', 'W', 'NW', etc,
  constraint PK_StopDirection( RouteID, Direction )
);
```

So a stop may be associated with one direction, two, or all directions.

```
StopID   Direction
    15           N
    15           S
    15           W
```

So stop #15 is available for Northbound, Southbound and Westbound routes.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer. But Direction is something different. The direction does not describe the orientation of the bus to the stop. The direction describes the route that stops at that stop. For example, sometimes the Eastbound bus and the Westbound bus stop at the same place. But sometimes the stop on one side of the street is only for the Eastbound bus, and the other side is for Westbound. In other words, I need a way to answer the question: "Does the Eastbound Route A bus stop here?" Is this more clear now?

Comment: @emersonthis I think so. So if a street runs East/West and the stop is on the North side of the street, it is available only for a Westbound bus.

Comment: Right. That is sometimes the case but other times not. So I need the model to be flexible enough to accommodate that